# Regarding Direction calculation using Gyroscope,Magnetometer and Accelerometer

Tags: rotation, sensors, direction

We are using MEMS tri axial sensor which has Accelerometer,Magnetometer and Gyrometer.We have also done Accelerometer and Magnetometer calibration.This sensor is used in borehole application.We have calculated Deviation of borehole using Accelerometer.Now we are stuck up in direction calculation free from rotation(i.e if the sensor rotates also the direction should not change).Is it possible to calculate rotation free Direction using the above three(Acce,Magnet,Gyro) readings. If yes please let me know .

Thanks,
S.Naseer

Comment: Try asking this question on Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks i have posted it...